# ANGULAR/IONIC ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have this error when I want to receive data from the server with a REST API and display it in an HTML component through a modal. In console if I get the data but in my HTML view not.

> ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

PedidodisponibleService.ts

```
export class PedidodisponibleService {

  private url = 'http://www.server.llama-ya.com';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getPedido(): Observable<Pdisponible[]>{
    const path = `${this.url}/PedidoDisponible`;
    return this.http.get<Pdisponible[]>(path);
  }
}
```

Interface

```
export interface Pdisponible {
    Valor?: true;
    Id?: number;
    Monto: string;
    Distancia: string;
    Tiempo: string;
    DondeCobrar: string;
}
```

modalpedido.page.ts

```
export class ModalpedidoPage implements OnInit {

    pedido: any = [];

  constructor(
    public modalController: ModalController,
    private pedidoDisponible: PedidodisponibleService
   ) { }

ngOnInit() {

    this.pedidoDisponible.getPedido().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.pedido = res as any;
        console.log(res);
      }, 
      error => console.log(error + "No podemos procesar pedidos")
      /*err => console.error(err)*/
    );
    }

  }
```

modalpedido.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

  <ion-content>

  <ion-card>

    <ion-item lines="none">
      <ion-label>
        <h1> Incoming Order </h1>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let pe of pedido">
      <ion-label>
       
        <h2> ORDER DESCRIPTION </h2>
        <h3> {{pe.Monto}} </h3> 
        <h3> {{pe.DondeCobrar}} </h3> 
        <p> {{pe.Distancia}} </p> 
        <p> {{pe.Tiempo}} </p> 
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Please post in English, or to post in Spanish, use [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that you don't received an array else and object. It's possible you received, e.g. some like `{data:[1,2,3]}`,

Then getPedido should be like

```
  this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(map(x=>x.data))
```

You see that we dont' return the response only the property "data" of the response.

Or in subscribe

```
this.pedidoDisponible.getPedido().subscribe(
      (res:any) => {
        this.pedido = res.data;
      },
```